# CSP3 Report-To header implementation

Tags: apache2, http-headers

## Issue

Many CSP validators like `cspvalidator.org` tell me that:

> A draft of the next version of CSP deprecates report-uri in favour of
>   a new report-to directive.

I found more information about this on [wicg.github.io](http://wicg.github.io/reporting/#header), but I didn't find an example / a solution.

## Question

**How do I properly implement the `Report-To` HTTP header in Apache 2?**

This doesn't throw an error but also does not execute the linked script in Firefox 49 and Chrome 53:

```
Header set Report-To "{'url': 'https://website.com/csp-report.php', 'group': 'csp-endpoint', 'max-age': 10886400}"
```

With the `Content-Security-Policy` header implemented like this:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; report-to csp-endpoint"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are examples in [the draft](https://wicg.github.io/reporting/#examples) of the Reporting-Endpoints directive:

```
Reporting-Endpoints = endpoint-1="https://example.com/reports"
```

Your rule is correctly created, as in it returns a valid JSON object, but since the Reporting API is still a draft, most UA haven't got around implementing it. You could simply have both, report-uri and Reporting-Endpoints header meanwhile if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `report-to` header has been replaced by a `report-uri` field in the CSP.   Here is a document from the Mozilla Foundation that explains how to use the reporting functionality of content security policies:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_CSP_violation_reports

It suggests putting the report URL directly into the CSP header like:

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; report-uri http://reportcollector.example.com/collector.cgi`

It also has detailed information about the format and syntax of the reports so that you can implement them yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's exactly the opposite from what really happens. The `report-to` directive is new while `report-uri` is going to be deprecated.

Comment: I haven't found any examples of how to use the separate header and browsers don't appear to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example implementation:

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self' report-to default`

and then adding another `Report-To` response header:

`Report-To: {"group":"default","max_age": 10886400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://example.com/reporting.php"}],"include_subdomains":true}`